# Pulseaudio no audio via bluetooth a2dp connection buildroot

Tags: bluetooth, debian, buildroot, pulseaudio, a2dp

**Edit:**

**I discovered, that if I run `parec | paplay --raw` it does play back properly.
How is this possible? There should be just a simple module-loopback error or something like that.**

I´m using the CHIP SBC from getchip.com to build an embedded bluetooth audio receiver.
getchip.com offers a debian linux and a customizable buildroot distribution.

I got everything working on the debian distribution with one exception. The volume control with iOS devices don´t work because of the lack of uinput inside the debian kernel.
That´s why i tried to get it to work with the buildroot distribution. It took me a while to get bluetoothd running with simple-agent, as well as pulseaudio built with bluetooth support and the dbus configuration.
I finally got everything ready.

**But:
I can connect to the sbc, but there is no sound playing on the headphone jack.**

My debugging steps so far:

- I´m able to play a local .wav file via `paplay`
  just fine.
- I allowed every communication via dbus
- the pulseaudio logs show, that sound is coming from the bluetooth source.
- the module-switch-on-connect does spawn a loopback from the bluetooth source to the same audio sink as `paplay` uses.

**Debug Logs:**

[Boot log](http://pastebin.com/vRAwSK1n)

[Pulseaudio verbose startup](http://pastebin.com/BkJ21Lvy)

```
/usr/bin/pulseaudio -vvvv --system --daemonize --disallow-exit
```

[Bluetoothd verbose connection](http://pastebin.com/G8UdQ3NR)

```
/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C -d &
```

and the bt-agent:

```
/usr/bin/bt-agent -d -c NoInputNoOutput -p /home/cubbo/.config/bluetooth-default-pin
```

[Pulseaudio verbose connection](http://pastebin.com/02NTT0m7)

**Configuration:**

[Pulseaudio system.pa](http://pastebin.com/UZcCxUmN)

[Pulseaudio daemon.conf](http://pastebin.com/Dqcg20sP)

[dbus system.conf](http://pastebin.com/CRMQsww7)

[dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf](http://pastebin.com/0f7BP8uA)

[dbus-1/system.d/pulseaudio-bluetooth.conf](http://pastebin.com/2N03LekS)

[bluetooth/audio.conf](http://pastebin.com/v1cNjDeD)

[bluetooth/main.conf](http://pastebin.com/TzMQEXJe)

I´m pretty sure that I just miss some little configuration and it´ll play just fine. But after nearly one week of debugging I wanted to ask you for help.

I hope I´ve done everything right with attaching the logs via pastebin.
I would appreciate your help!

Thanks!
Greetings, Phil.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Antergos, A2DP was not available in pulseaudio.

A2DP was available only when restarting bluethooth service by "systemctl restart bluethooth"

It resulted to be a problem caused by GDM that opened another instance of pulseaudio and captured the bluethooth device. I prevented pulseaudio capturing bluethooth device by masking it for GDM user.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Connecting_works.2C_but_I_cannot_play_sound

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user

$ ln -s /dev/null ~/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket
```

[restart required]